Looking for title of a Ursula K. Le Guin story/novel that features four-way marriage/romantic relationships
That's it.  I don't know any more.

Could this be Mountain Ways by Ursula K. Le Guin? You can read in in full here

Marriage on O is a foursome, the sedoretu—a man and a woman from the
Morning moiety and a man and a woman from the Evening moiety. You’re
expected to have sex with both your spouses of the other moiety, and
not to have sex with your spouse of your own moiety. So each sedoretu
has two expected heterosexual relationships, two expected homosexual
relationships, and two forbidden heterosexual relationships.

As pointed out in a comment, this concept of polyamorous marriage on the planet O has featured in at least one other Le Guin story, Another Story or A Fisherman of the Inland Sea

The plot follows a scientist from the fictional planet O who turns his
back on the quiet rural life of his planet to join in the development
of a faster than light technology called Churten Theory. To do this he
leaves for another planet called Hain, a journey that will take a long
time and as a result he must say goodbye to everyone and everything he
has ever known.


Thank you.  I don't know that there is a specific, single story I'm looking for.  I'll have to read all that people suggest.  After I've done that I'll be able to describe them to the person that originally mentioned this to me and ask which, if any, of them was the one they were recalling.

The marriage system on O also appears in "Another Story: A Fisherman of the Inland Sea", but it is only a minor part of that story.

To put things a little bit straighter: Le Guin created the society of O, with its evening and morning "moeties", for 'A Fisherman of the Inland Sea'; then revisited it in at least two further stories, 'Unchosen Love' and 'Mountain Ways', which were both included in the collection The Birthday of the World. In the collection's foreword she joked that it "may be mere conservation of energy" that led her to explore the idea further, after putting in a lot of effort to working out exactly how the relationships would work for the earlier story.
